# Format the body of the outlook appointment item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to create an outlook appointment from an ASP.NET web site version 2.0. I am making use of the interface `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` to create the appointment. But my exact requirement is to display the body (description) of the appointment in HTML format (which includes images, links etc) instead of plain text. The only method
I can see in the appointmentItem is ‘body’. This method only writes the plain text not the formatted HTML body.

So is there any alternate approach to format the description (body) of an appointment? Please help me out with this.

Comment: Don't ever use Office Interop from an ASP.NET application. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like

```
.Body = "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 Test}"
```

Source : http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-91618.html

Comment: This seems like rich text formatting. I think it will be a nightmare to design all the contents of the body (includes images, links, h1 tag, p tag etc) in RTF. Could you please suggest me an alternative for this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible even with RTF. Because in MSDN it says like - Returns or sets a String (string in C#) representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. Read/write. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.body.aspx